# Right Click - Getting the menu appears next to the Cursor

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have script below, in which when I do right click on the cursor, a menu will appear.  A problem is a menu appears elsewhere instead of next to the cursor.
What I am missing here.  Please take a look.
Thanks.

```
 menu.show = function (e) {
        if (menu.visible) {
            menu.close();
        } else {
            var pos = $(this).offset();
            pos.top = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
            pos.left = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;

            panel.css({ width: '100%', height: $(document).height(), 'background-color': 'transparent' }).show();
            menu.data('trigger', $(this));
            menu.css(pos).fadeIn('fast');
            menu.visible = true;
        }
        return false;
    };
```

I also try this, but it doesn't work, either.

```
 menu.show = function (e) {
        if (menu.visible) {
            menu.close();
        } else {
            var pos = $(this).offset();
            top = e.pageX;
            left = e.pageY;

 panel.css({ width: '100%', height: $(document).height(), 'background-color': 'transparent' }).show();
            menu.data('trigger', $(this));
            menu.css(pos).fadeIn('fast');
            menu.visible = true;
        }
        return false;
    };
```

Comment: Please show us the HTML and CSS for this too. Probably some missing/wrong CSS.

Comment: @Sergiu, Thank you very much for your concern!  I Check the HTML and CSS, there is nothing related.

Comment: Left/right are CSS properties. They rely on the element having a position: absolute prop too, and the offsets have to be computed relative to an offset parent, probably the whole page since you are subtracting from pageX and pageY. Meaning you need to make sure there is no other position: relative parent

Comment: Hi Sergiu, I just checked it again, the only CSS getting involved are inside `panel.css`.  How can I write a CSS to make the menu appear on the right or left of the cursor when I do right-click? Thanks

Comment: Well, you are not showing us `panel.css`.

Comment: Hi Sergiu, the panel.css is in the script above.  it has only a few `panel.css({ width: '100%', height: $(document).height(), 'background-color': 'transparent' }).show();`

Comment: Oh, was thinking it's an actual .css file. `menu.css` is what sets `left` and `right` on the menu. So `menu` needs to be absolutely positioned. I don't see anything (CSS or JS) setting `position: absolute` on it.

Comment: Hi Sergiu, position: absolute is added, but the menu shows far away the cursor!  Any idea?